# Criteria in relation between entities - Grails

Tags: grails, criteria, grails-2.0, hibernate-criteria, grails-domain-class

I have an app with the following entities:

**Topic:**

```
class Topic {

   UUID id
   String description
   String name
   boolean visibility = true

   // Relation
   static hasMany = [tests:Test]
   ...
}
```

**Test:**

```
class Test {

    UUID id
    boolean active = true
    String description
    ...

    static hasMany = [evaluationsTest: Evaluation]
    static belongsTo = [topic: Topic, catalog: Catalog]
}
```

When I show all visible topics to the user I request the query:

```
def visibleTopics = Topic.findAllByVisibility(true, [sort:"name", order:"asc"])
```

This query returns me for example: `[['English'], ['Spanish']]`. Then, I can show the full information about each topic to the user.

But I also want to indicate to the user the number of active test in each visible topic.

For example:

```
English topic has 2 active test.
Spanish topic has a total of 2 test. One is active and the other is not.
German topic has not any active test.
```

Then I need a query whose result is: `def activeTotalEachTopic = [[2],[1],[0]]` and I can pass the `activeTotalEachTopic` variable to the view (.gsp).

**Solution:**

From the first query where I can obtain all visible topics, I get the number of active test.

```
def visibleTopics = Topic.findAllByVisibility(true, [sort:"name", order:"asc"])

def numberActiveTest = []

activeTopics.each { topic ->
    def result = Test.findAllByTopicAndActive(topic, true).size()
    numberActiveTest.push(result)
}
```

And I pass to the view both variables.

```
render view: 'home', model: [activeTopics: activeTopics, numberActiveTest: numberActiveTest]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is grouping so that you get the count per group, rather than a total count.

You also need to change the join type from the default inner join to an outer join in order for topics without an active test to return 0. However, a side-effect of this is that it changes how association properties are referenced due to the alias that's created by the join. Something like this:

```
import static org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.*

def activeTotalEachTopic =  Topic.createCriteria().list() {
    createAlias('tests', 't', LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)

    eq 'visibility', true

    or {
        eq 't.active', true
        isNull 't.id'
    }

    projections {
       groupProperty 'name'
       count()
    }        
    order ("name", "asc")
}
```

Now, another issue to address is that the output would be something like this due to the grouping: `[['English', 2],['Spanish', 1],['German', 0]]`. So what you can do is collect the second item in each sub-list:

```
activeTotalEachTopic*.getAt(1)

// Which is the equivalent of...

activeTotalEachTopic.collect { it[1] }
```

Comment: Thanks. It does not work perfectly. It only shows the topics with active test, hence: `[['English', 2],['Spanish', 1]]`. **German topic** is not in the list.

Comment: OK, I fixed the null issue. The problem is that when there's no associated test, `t.active` becomes null, which causes the condition to fail. So a null check will fix that.

Comment: The problem continues. Topics without active test are not shown. If projections section is omitted, it only appears two topics; the third doesn't appear (German).

Comment: Just play with it! Note: You need the projections to do a count, or any type or grouping. And knowing SQL is *very* handy. http://docs.grails.org/2.2.x/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html

Comment: Yes, I know it that projections is necessary. It only was a example to check if the query works well or not. In this case, it does't work well because the topics without active test aren't obtained. And this why?

Comment: Yes, that means the left outer join is not happening. I do not know why; I do know using an alias works. You can try HQL. Something like this: `def activeTotalEachTopic = Topic.executeQuery('SELECT size(b) FROM Topic AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN a.tests AS b WHERE a.visibility = true AND (b.active = true OR b.id IS NULL) ORDER BY a.name ASC')`

Comment: You forgot the `GROUP BY a.name`. The result is the same. German does not appear. _LEFT OUTER JOIN_ doesn't work.

Comment: No, I did not. `size()` is not a grouping function. Oh well, I give up. I suggest writing a SQL query, and then translating it into a criteria query or HQL. You'll find that indeed, a left outer join is needed.